# My CodePlayer is not working on my Blogger post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my blog - http://quickeasycoder.blogspot.com/2018/07/code-player.html

It is not working as same as it was working in my browser. Every section up there in the blog come and merge upon each other.

This is working perfectly in my Google Chrome but it's not the case when I have uploaded it to my Blogger post. I think code is perfect but the thing may be in the layout of the blog. What should be done now?

```html
<html>

    <head>

        <title>jQuery</title>


 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>




  <style type="text/css">


            body {

                font-family: sans-serif;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;

            }

            #header {

                width:100%;
                background-color: #EEEEEE;
                padding:5px;
                height: 30px;

            }

            #logo {

                float:left;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 120%;
                padding: 3px 5px;

            }

            #buttonContainer {

                width:233px;
                margin: 0 auto;

            }

            .toggleButton {

                float:left;
                border: 1px solid grey;
                padding: 6px;
                border-right: none;
                font-size: 90%;

            }

            #html {

                border-top-left-radius: 4px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;

            }

            #output {

                border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
                border-right: 1px solid grey;

            }

            .active {

                background-color: #E8F2FF;

            }

            .highlightedButton {

                background-color: grey;

            }

            textarea {

                resize: none;
                border-top: none;
                border-color: grey;

            }

            .panel {

                float:left;
                width: 50%;
                border-left: none;
            }

            iframe {

                border:none;

            }

            .hidden {

                display: none;

            }

           #intro{margin:10px;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>


        <p id="intro"> Learn HTML| CSS| JAVASCRIPT without any text-editor by using Code-Player <br>
        Built using HTML| CSS| JAVASCRIPT| jQuery</p>

        <div id="header">

            <div id="logo">

                CodePlayer

            </div>

            <div id="buttonContainer">

                <div class="toggleButton active" id="html">HTML</div>

                <div class="toggleButton" id="css">CSS</div>

                <div class="toggleButton" id="javascript">JavaScript</div>

                <div class="toggleButton active" id="output">Output</div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="bodyContainer">

            <textarea id="htmlPanel" class="panel"> <p id="paragraph">Hello World!</p></textarea>

            <textarea id="cssPanel" class="panel hidden"> p { color: green; }</textarea>

            <textarea id="javascriptPanel" class="panel hidden">document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "Hello Rob!";</textarea>

            <iframe id="outputPanel" class="panel"></iframe>


        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function updateOutput() {

                $("iframe").contents().find("html").html("<html><head><style type='text/css'>" + $("#cssPanel").val() + "</style></head><body>" + $("#htmlPanel").val() + "</body></html>");

                document.getElementById("outputPanel").contentWindow.eval($("#javascriptPanel").val());



            }

            $(".toggleButton").hover(function() {

                $(this).addClass("highlightedButton");

            }, function() {

                $(this).removeClass("highlightedButton");

            });

            $(".toggleButton").click(function() {

                $(this).toggleClass("active");

                $(this).removeClass("highlightedButton");

                var panelId = $(this).attr("id") + "Panel";

                $("#" + panelId).toggleClass("hidden");

                var numberOfActivePanels = 4 - $('.hidden').length;

                $(".panel").width(($(window).width() / numberOfActivePanels) - 10);

            })

            $(".panel").height($(window).height() - $("#header").height() - 15);

            $(".panel").width(($(window).width() / 2) - 10);

            updateOutput();

            $("textarea").on('change keyup paste', function() {

                updateOutput();


            });



        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: a lot of CMS type blogs prohibit posting code by default to "protect" from dangerous code. Sometimes its part of the validation of the WYSIWYG editors

Comment: Now what can be done?
What shld be done so that it works

Comment: try to embed an `<iframe>` most blogs will allow that

Comment: Bro I m a beginner i know what <iframe> is 
but where to embed and how

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since a lot of blog platforms prohibit embedding code sometimes you are able to accomplish the task by using an `<iframe>` similar to what is here

```html
<iframe height='265' scrolling='no' title='BPaNNq' src='//codepen.io/happymacarts/embed/BPaNNq/?height=265&theme-id=0&default-tab=html,result&embed-version=2' frameborder='no' allowtransparency='true' allowfullscreen='true' style='width: 100%;'>See the Pen <a href='https://codepen.io/happymacarts/pen/BPaNNq/'>BPaNNq</a> by Joseph L. Bradfield (<a href='https://codepen.io/happymacarts'>@happymacarts</a>) on <a href='https://codepen.io'>CodePen</a>.
```

```html
or something like this one i found (looks familiar)

<iframe height='265' scrolling='no' title='Code player' src='//codepen.io/akashdevgan/embed/JGbGOQ/?height=265&theme-id=0&default-tab=css,result&embed-version=2' frameborder='no' allowtransparency='true' allowfullscreen='true' style='width: 100%;'>See the Pen <a href='https://codepen.io/akashdevgan/pen/JGbGOQ/'>Code player</a> by Akash Devgan (<a href='https://codepen.io/akashdevgan'>@akashdevgan</a>) on <a href='https://codepen.io'>CodePen</a>.
```

I don't think that it works to embed in the snippet here but this might work on your blogger site  try it out

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't debug yours, wrote my own version of codeplayer.

You may need to refer these. [Make HTML elements as contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable), [CSS Custom Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".body").get(0).style.setProperty("--contentwidth", 100/$(".active").length+"%");
    
    $(".codetype").click(function(){
        $(this).hasClass("active") ? $(this).removeClass("active") : $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".codecontent").eq($(this).index()).toggle();
        $(".body").get(0).style.setProperty("--contentwidth", 100/$(".active").length+"%");
    });
});
```

```css
.container
{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    max-height:400px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.header
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

.codetype
{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
.codetype > span
{
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
.codetype:first-child
{
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
}
.codetype:last-child
{
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
}
.body
{
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
.codecontent
{
    height:100%;
    width:var(--contentwidth);
    background:yellow;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.active
{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div id="" class="codetype active"><span>HTML</span></div>
        <div id="" class="codetype active"><span>CSS</span></div>
        <div id="" class="codetype active"><span>JS</span></div>
        <div id="" class="codetype active"><span>Output</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div id="" class="codecontent" contenteditable=true>HTML</div>
        <div id="" class="codecontent" contenteditable=true>CSS</div>
        <div id="" class="codecontent" contenteditable=true>JS</div>
        <div id="" class="codecontent">Output</div>
    </div>
</div>
```